# How to generate a Key pair in the Secure Enclave, which I can use from the System Keychain

Tags: swift, macos, active-directory, wifi

how do I create a Key-pair in the Secure Enclave, which I can access from the System Keychain?

For a internal project, I need a AD Certificate, where the private key should be stored in the SE. For this I write a Swift Application which generates a key pair in the SE and build a CSR from this.

Now I have created a AD Certificate out of the CSR. Because of the Keychain access groups I can't access private key.

Is there another way to create a key pair in the secure enclave where I can access the private key from the keychain? Or does anyone know how to connect with the Certificate to a company Wi-Fi / VPN?